# callbacks for safari alert box cancel button

Tags: javascript, ios, mobile-safari, alert

I'm creating a web page for downloading iOS app from enterprise store.

But i'm finding some limitation in it.
One of them is
when we click on a button we get the alert box for install(attached image)

Can we get the callback for the cancel or install button on safari ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Alerts are not exposed to the browser.

Comment: What can be an alternative to this?